# Random Big Integer In Range JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, random, biginteger

I need a random integer between 0 and an integer with over 1000 decimal places.

Working with integers this large is easy with: [big-integer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/big-integer) (NPM), but there is no random method, and Math.random() doesn't express enough precision to cover the domain.

Does anyone know a clever way of generating pseudo random integers in a large range in JavaScript?

Comment: Note that [big-integer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/big-integer) now has a `randBetween` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think best solution for your case in Node.JS is [`crypto.randomBytes(size, [callback]);`](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback)

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to convert a buffer of random bytes into an integer between X and Y inclusively? It's far less trivial than your short answer would make it seem.

Comment: I could do this only for normal integers, but as `big-integer` module does not support hexadecimal numbers it is very difficult to do this for large numbers

Comment: Ah, okay that makes sense. `big-integer` seems to represent values using an integer array as a large base representation, getting a good distribution would be an algorithm far more needy than it's purpose.

Comment: If the maintainer(s) of the module will implement hex (https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js/issues/6), I could implement a more universal solution for large random integers

Comment: Just as an update (I'm the maintainer of the `big-integer` library), there is now a `randBetween` method, and hexidecimal numbers are supported.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var biformat = require('biguint-format');

// Adjust # bytes as needed
var seed = biformat(crypto.randomBytes(8), 'dec');
bigInt(seed);
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-bigint

```
const random = require('random-bigint')

// synchronous api, generates a random number between 0 and 2**128-1
const num = random(128) // 128 bits
```

FYI, ** is Exponentiation

Answer (score 0):

```js
function genRandomNumber(byteCount, radix) {
  return BigInt('0x' + crypto.randomBytes(byteCount).toString('hex')).toString(radix)
}

// to genrate a 8 byte number in decimal format string
const randomNumber = genRandomNumber(8, 10)
```

Comment: you have a mistake in `genRnadomNumber`