# How to generate a random `bigint` number between two `bigint` numbers in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, bigint

I have saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70677751/how-to-generate-random-bigint-within-a-range-in-plain-javascript-not-node-js) but it does not provide an answer.

I would want something like this:

```
let randomBigInt = generateRandomBigInt(0, 920392947394829032030943);
console.log(randomBigInt); // 4893848594594
```

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715110/random-big-integer-in-range-javascript

Comment: Here's what I created: https://tsplay.dev/wje7vW with a frequency test to see if it's still more or less uniformly distributed. It's not perfect... very large ranges will actually make it impossible to generate certain numbers. You could fix this by using more digits, though... but there's bound to be some inaccuracy given large enough inputs. However, it seems random enough.

Comment: Note that "more or less uniformly distributed" over a range larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` implies that every value in that range should have approximately the same chance of being returned.  Which is not going to happen if you just multiply `Math.random()` to the range, since that doesn't have enough bits in it.

Comment: I've got [this](https://tsplay.dev/weLDVW) but I don't know how to verify that it behaves as desired for large ranges.  Essentially you need to come up with as many bits of randomness as you need to cover the range.

Comment: @jcalz I was headed the same way with the bytes of `crypto.getRandomValues`, masking the bytes to the msb of the range. Difficult to know if it will skew, but I think the concept is good.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `crypto.getRandomValues` as the random number source to generate random `bigint` over a nearly arbitrarily large (524288 bit) range without losing precision.

Of course, it rapidly becomes infeasible to test that it is non-skewed.

```js
function mask(arr: Uint8Array, numBits: number) {
    let idx = 0;
    let b = numBits;
    while (idx < arr.length) {
        arr[idx] = 
            b <= 0 ? 0 : b > 0 && b < 8 ? arr[idx] & ((1 >> b) - 1) : arr[idx];
        ++idx;
        b -= 8;
    }
}
```

```js
function getBitCount(v: bigint) {
    let x = v;
    let c = 0;
    do {
        ++c;
        x >>= 1n;
    } while (x > 0n)
    return c;
}
```

```js
function bigRandomInRange(v1: bigint, v2: bigint) {
    const min = v1 > v2 ? v2 : v1;
    const r = v1 - v2;
    const range = r < 0 ? -r : r;
    if (range === 0n) {
        return min;
    }
    const bitCount = getBitCount(range);
    const byteCount = Math.ceil(bitCount / 8);
    const arr = new Uint8Array(byteCount);
    for (; ;) {
        crypto.getRandomValues(arr);
        mask(arr, bitCount);
        const v = arr.reduce(
            (acc, curr, i) => (1n << (BigInt(i) * 8n)) * BigInt(curr) + acc, 0n);
        if (v < range) {
            return min + v;
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYGcDWAKVAnPALkQFUYwoAOAQQNQE8AaRMEZAIRinWNeQCMApngCUiAN4AoRDMQAbQVEQwAJgA9EAXkQAGANzTZCpfy0s2nbgdmIA7gAsYCxNlUaAPInx4AdArAA5lD2YlI2Nt4A2m4AulqG4eGm7to6iAD8uojEpgB8WQBkBYjJiJQZXgTR6nHF2NgAjIi5+fxiALSIDWLEUbHWiYgA1ENuA4mm7dqU44gAvpILkqCQsAiIAYqWAMJw4FDYAG45MAHkUKEJ8oqIGtqHs8aIEGb6VypwElc2IxCzNhoWtoGmBZnM7I5nNhAbowCIrnhFCA8Eg-otJMtwNB4Eh+KcAEqoMAfZAASTAhMCgiODROZwozEOACY6edLjYIAh0EpkOQzIcmvlmRVhcQBbNOWBuYg8Pymp1mRKuUo8ETNmZZZ40pl2rLiHhZjBgC5VVStJpUnCvoMZUiUShyGCrpLpXioLt9mZNlAdnsKNhTZsREqpSZ6FBBB6KGYALKoYI+CCCJzYN1RpQAejKwedysqsu0YEEtlI5xodHoqfDkb9F1mwDgsuwekQenZgwgeHoAAcoHAfN7KSSAGqoOQgQToXAEHM2tBYad4Zhp2uzjt5w5mbw+REqEBJ7DfQa4CAQZgQZFL5RiTT5RpIdyebCcALkg4wMQAKjKcK-iBfb7YBeM7DF4p7MDocL-LIRouJuniBoI7Y2jIiJQMiSC8kgQyIA8R4yAsNgLEsGIunACh+HAASpgSRIkuSlKbNgkHMA0TIAMwACwAKwAGy-noQA)

Answer (score 0):

```
function randomBigInt(max: bigint | number | string): bigint;
function randomBigInt(min: bigint | number | string, max: bigint | number | string): bigint;
function randomBigInt(min: bigint | number | string, max?: bigint | number | string): bigint {
    if (max === undefined) return randomBigInt(0n, min);
    // choose if you want to allow not-bigints yourself
    // this wrapper allows `bigint | number | string` (you may want to keep at least `bigint | number`
    min = BigInt(min); 
    max = BigInt(max);

    // choose what happens when input order is invalid (e.g. throw error)
    // this wrapper keeps `min` in and `max` out of generatable numbers
    if (min <= max)
      return min + _generateRandomBigInt(max - min);
    else 
      return max - 1 - _generateRandomBigInt(min - max);
}

/**
 * This is tha basic function to generate random bigint.
 * @param max exclusive maximum
 * (c) <CC-BY-SA-4.0 or Unlicense> Dimava, 2023
 */
function _generateRandomBigInt(max: bigint): bigint {
    if (max < 0) throw new Error("generateRandomBigInt cannot generate negative BigInt");
    if (max === 0n) return 0n;

    const POWER = 64n;
    const FILTER = (1n << POWER) - 1n;

    // 1. Create an BigInt64Array representation of max number
    let num = max;
    const maxList: bigint[] = [];
    while (num) {
        maxList.unshift(num & FILTER);
        num >>= POWER;
    }
    const maxArray = BigInt64Array.from(maxList);

    // 2. Generate the random number
    const rndArray = crypto.getRandomValues(maxArray.slice());

    // 3. Trim the random number highest bits 
    // to reduce failure rate to <50%
    let trim = 1n;
    while (maxArray[0] > trim) trim <<= 1n;
    trim--;
    rndArray[0] &= trim;

    // 4. Convert to bigint
    let rnd = 0n;
    for (let i = 0; i < rndArray.length; i++) {
        rnd <<= POWER;
        rnd += rndArray[i];
    }

    // 5. Check for failure (the random number being higher then max)
    // and retry if needed
    if (rnd >= max) return _generateRandomBigInt(max);
    return rnd;
}

console.log(randomBigInt(1000n))
console.log(randomBigInt(1000n, 2000n))
console.log(randomBigInt(-1000n, 0n))
```

Answer (score -1):

> The Math.random() static method returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number that's greater than or equal to 0 and less than 1, with approximately uniform distribution over that range — which you can then scale to your desired range. [mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

You can generate a random float, which will be between 0 and 1. You can then multiply it to be in the BigInt limits. Passing it in the `const bigIntValue = BigInt(yourRandomMultipliedValue)` will convert it into a bigint type.

Comment: "multiply it to be in the BigInt limits" How? It'll lose precision.

Comment: @kelsny I'm sorry, I couldn't exactly get your point. If you mean that it will no longer be an integer, after the multiplication a `Math.floor(x)` will round x to the largest integer less than or equal to _x_

Comment: Provide code in your answer then. It's not clear what you mean by "multiply it to be in the BigInt limits".

Comment: A javascript number has limited precision, say for simplicity its 64-bits. That means there are at most 2^64 possible "random" integers that can be generated in any interval no matter how large. That means almost all of the values in his example range of [0, 920392947394829032030943) are impossible to generate. That is undesirable.